# Getting highest number in array then adding a new value in that array with +1 of the previous doesn't work - C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm making a filename manager that searches a folder for files, extracts a number in the filename, puts them in an array, sorts them in descending order. Then i obtain the Highest number and add 1 to it then use it as the next filename.

Example:

- Files in folder A: file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
- If i create a new file, it should be named file4.txt automatically.

But that isn't what is happening

Consider:

CheckDir() simply finds where a special folder is and returns it. (i.e C:/Users/Name/Appdata)

Prefix is a user-set string, we'll use 'file' for this example.

```cs
public static string ProcessPath()
{

    string path = CheckDir();

    if (path != null) //if there is a path
    {

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, prefix + "*.png");
        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(mainpath, "filescheck.txt"), string.Join(",", files)); /////////////


        if (files.Length != 0) //if there is files that match the prefix then -->>>
        {
            File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(mainpath, "filesnotnull.txt"), "hi"); //////

            Nullable<int> highest = null;
            var fileNames = files;
            var numberList = new List<int>();
            int number = 0;
            string numtouse = "";

            foreach (var name in fileNames)
            {
                string m = Regex.Match(name, @"\d+").Value;
                var isNumber = Int32.TryParse(m.ToString(), out number);

                if (isNumber) numberList.Add(number);
            }

            highest = numberList.OrderByDescending(x => x).FirstOrDefault();

            var result = (highest.ToString() ?? null);
            numtouse = (highest + 1).ToString();

            if (result != null)
            {
                string filename = prefix + numtouse + ".png";
                string givepath = Path.Combine(path, filename);
                return givepath;
            } else
            {
                return null;
            }

        } else // if there is no files with the prefix then -->>>
        {

            string filename = prefix + "1.png";
            string givepath = Path.Combine(path, filename);
            return givepath;

        }
    } else //retry if no path
    {
        MoozSS.TakeSS();
        return null;

    }
}
```

Output when used:

- file1.png
- file18.png
- file18.png (overwrites the file)
- ...

Expected Output:

- file1.png
- file2.png
- file3.png
- ...

How do i fix this so it functions the way it should.

Forgive the code if it's ugly, I'm just trying to get it working first.

Comment: add some print statements to display the content of numberList.OrderByDescending(x => x). BTW your regular expression seems to match single digit only which may not be what you want

Comment: and you can do List.Sort instead of the descending stuff

Comment: Also, try to use `string m = Regex.Match(name, @"\d+").Value;` for your **regex** as it will get you a whole number from your string, in your case you will get only a single digit.

Comment: This is odd `string[] files = files = Directory.GetFiles`. You have an extra `files =` in there. Does it compile? Does it do what you want? Doing this in `c:\program files` is a _really_ bad idea (two reasons: 1) I think only admins can write there, and 2) there is important stuff there, a bad bug could hurt). You also re-call `Directory.GetFiles` soon afterwards

Comment: @Flydog57 I'm writing what I need in Appdata, I just used Program Files as an example. Whoops. Yes it does compile and there are 0 errors in my IDE (Visual Studio 2019).

Comment: @Miraziz I tried that out, and somehow: file1.png, file18.png

Comment: I have updated the code and the post based on Flydog57 and Miraziz.

Comment: If `files` was a `List<string>`, you could just sort that list and then run the regex against just one string. Don't forget that you'll have to detect file exists state when you attempt to create the new file, because some other process may get in ahead of you. But then all you have to do is keep bumping `numtouse` until you succeed.

Comment: @jwdonahue So basically I could've just used File.Exist() then if it does, add +1 to the number until it doesn't and then save it that way?

Comment: Maybe, but if you already have a dozen `X(n).png` files, it might be faster to get the `X*.png` list first, so you don't have to retry a dozen times. But ya, implement the simplest thing that works, then measure performance in your real environment and adjust accordingly.

Comment: @jwdonahue Thanks for the enlightenment. Fortunately, my program isn't meant to be used past a couple hundred files, I will still have the regex method as an option in case people really want to abuse the program(once I get the RegEx method working of course).

Comment: While I have a solution working for me in replace of the RegEx, I will not consider the alternative as a solution to why the RegEx method is not working

Comment: If you're looking for much more help than you've already received, you should post an [mcve].

Comment: Why are you sorting a list?  Can’t you just retain the maximum number as you read each file name?

Comment: @RBarryYoung I am aware of that replaced it with code that doesn't need to create an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This is less of a /this fixes the issue/ and more /this avoids the issue/.

This is the code that I ended up using.

```cs
 public static string ProcessPath()
        {
            string path = CheckDir();

            if (path != null)//if there is a path
            {

                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, prefix + "*.png");

                if (files.Length != 0)//if there is files that match the prefix then -->>>
                {
                    int count = 2;

                    while(File.Exists(Path.Combine(path, (prefix + count + ".png"))))
                    {
                        count = count + 1;
                    }

                    string filename = prefix + count + ".png";
                    string givepath = Path.Combine(path, filename);
                    return givepath;


                }
                else // if there is no files with the prefix then -->>>
                {

                    string filename = prefix + "1.png";
                    string givepath = Path.Combine(path, filename);
                    return givepath;

                }

            }
            else //retry if no path
            {

                MoozSS.TakeSS();
                return null;

            }
        }
```

It scanning through every possible file should not be an issue for performance as the program is not meant for scanning through a lot of files, unless the user really abuses it.

Thanks to those who pointed out issues and optimizations in the comments.